# Using jQuery code to replace my javascript XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am kind of new to JavaScript library's. I wanted to replace my current code with a JS lib jQuery. My current code looks like this.

```js
function myajax() 
  {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "http://localhost:8080/Marker1/webresources/org.sample.marker/markerlist";
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
   {
   myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
     }
    function myFunction(data) {
            myArr = JSON.parse(data);   // parsing JSON
 updateMap(data);   
    }
```

Comment: i am using GET method only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/Marker1/webresources/org.sample.marker/markerlist',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(responseText){
   var jsonData = JSON.stringify(responseText); 
    myArr = JSON.parse(jsonData );   // parsing JSON
    updateMap(myArr); 
  }
});
```

More information about the ajax function in the [jquery-API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`jQuery.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/):

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/Marker1/webresources/org.sample.marker/markerlist";
$.get(url, function(data) {
    myArr = JSON.parse(data);   // parsing JSON
    updateMap(data);
});
```

The anonymous function will be the callback. Of course, you can keep it in a separate declaration, as you had it:

```
function myFunction(data) {
    myArr = JSON.parse(data);   // parsing JSON
    updateMap(data);   
}
```

and just use the pointer to it at the `$.get()` call:

```
$.get(url, myFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery doco](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

```
$.get( "http://localhost:8080/Marker1/webresources/org.sample.marker/markerlist", function( data ) {
   myFunction(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

Post:

```
$.post(url, jsonData, function(res) { 
   //res what is returned from the server 
});
```

Get:

```
$.get(url, jsonData, function(res) { 
   //res what is returned from the server 
});
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: jsonData,
  success: successMethod,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Links:

[jQuery post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)
[jQuery get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)
[jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)